# Java creating a roster of unknown size

Tags: java, database, arrays

I'm posting this as a pick your brain kind of question.  Is an array the appropriate type of data holder for a roster of unknown size?

I am looking to create a small class with 3 methods

> 1. addToRoster //which would add a name to the proposed Array taking in an array and a String.
> 2. getRoster //which would return the elements of the roster printed to the console.
> 3. remFrRoster // which would take a name, cycle through the roster and remove it if found.

I'm really a beginner at Java.  I've only been programming about a week and looking to find out a few things.  One, is this an appropriate design methodology for a class?  Two, are arrays the preferred method for storing a roster of Strings? Lastly,  do i have to initialize my array to a definite size or can i have it change size as it approaches the limits of the size it is initialized to?

thanks,
pano

Comment: If the number of elements is unknown then an array really is appropriate. While you can resize the array manually, the [Collections API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) provides classes that can do this for you automatically

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I think @MadProgrammer probably meant to say "isn't appropriate". It is really a lot easier to use one of the Collections classes, as suggested, because they'll do the resizing for you.

Comment: @Simon :P Thanks!  Yes it's meant to be **isn't**

Answer (score 2):

You could use an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Player> roster = new ArrayList<Player>();  
roster.add(new Player(32));  
System.out.println(roster.get(0).getAge());
```

An ArrayList is essentially the same thing as an array, but it's size can be changed. Only use an ArrayList if the number of players on the roster is going to change *while the program is running.* i.e. If you are going to read the players in from a file just use an array, but if you are going to create an indeterminate amount of players after the program has started, use an ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Collection instead of an array to dynamically resize the store based on the number of elements.

- A [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) would be appropriate to store arbitrary number of elements.
- A [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) would be appropriate to store arbitrary number of objects keyed using an attribute of the object.

If your `Roster` happens to contains attributes other than the Name, then you can use a `Map` to store your `Roster` objects.

- addToRoster would simply put an element in the Map as `map.put(roster.getName(), roster)`.
- getRoster would iterate through the `map.values()` collection and prints each roster object.
- remFrRoster would simply removes the roster object using the name specified, `map.remove(name)`. If the return value from this call is null, it means there is no roster object with that name.

HTH.

Comment: thank you.  I will look into maps as they sound more aligned to the functionality i hope to achieve.